# Passing Variable to 7zip from powershell

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I can see that the there have been similar question answered but nothing seems to have the answers I'm looking for, I have tried using the solutions/modifying them to suit my needs but am unable to get the correct outputs.

My main question is: Can you pass Powershell variables to 7zip's command line.

Currently i have the script:

```
##########Alias Setting##########
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"}
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

############################################
#### Variables 

$filePath = "D:\Logs\test\201310\" #location to look in

$Archive = "D:\Logs\Test\201310\"

$Extension = "*.log" #extensions to look for

$Days = "30" #Number of days past today's date that will be archived

$CutDay = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays($Days)

$log = Get-ChildItem $filepath -include $Extension -recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $CutDay}

########### END of VARABLES ##################

 foreach ($File in $log)   #current gui output - temp only using for debugging purpose if required and to confirm files.
    {
        write-host "File Name : $File " $File.LastWriteTime 
    }

    foreach ($file in $log) # actually zipping
   {
    $archivename = $_.CutDay
      sz a -t7z $archivename $archivename -m0=PPMd
   }

########### END OF SCRIPT ##########
```

What i would like to have is have the 7zip command line read the file name and destination from variables, I plan to try and make this as a generic script as possible so the $archivename would depend on folder name and current date.

I would like the script to be able to read the locations it is zipping via parameters but currently I cannot get it to read the variables!

Any help would be appreciate or if you require clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the best way to pass parameter to an executable is using the [splatting parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) (`@variablename`):

```powershell
$7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

$parameter = @('a', '-t7z', '-m0=PPMd', "$target", "$source")
&$7zipPath @parameter
```

> sz a -t7z $archivename $archivename -m0=PPMd

There are two `$archivename` variables you pass to 7zip. The first should be the Target (e.g. `c:\test.zip`) and the second the Source (e.g `c:\test.text`)

Comment: Thanks you for the information, i may be using the command wrong or setting the viarables wrong but i am getting an error when running this. "$Archivename: WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified." then goes to "Updating archive $Archivename.7z", it doesnt seem to be reading the variables for $Archivename which i have set up earlier on. `foreach ($file in $log)
 {
 $Archivename = "Archive201310"
 $7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
 $parameter = @('a', '-t7z', '$Archivename', '$Archivename', '-m0=PPMd')
 &$7zipPath @parameter
}
`

Comment: apologies, hit enter before i had finished typing!

Comment: ohh, You have to put the variables in double quotes othwise they are just strings. Updated my answer.

Comment: i have done this but still nothing, i have changed the first variable to the $filePath variable but is returning the error still for $Archivename and now saying "updating archive $filePath.7z".

Comment: ah that makes sense will give that a go!

Comment: sorry, I didn't tested the script before I posted it. Now it should work ;)

Comment: that has worked! thank you!, could you point me towards some resources that may help with scripting in general?